# Count the Number of Positive Integer Solutions to $\prod_{i=1}^{k}x_i\le N$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, divisor-counting-function

Given a fixed integer $k$ and a large positive integer $N$, I'd like to count the number of positive integer solutions to the equation $\prod_{i=1}^{k}x_i\le N$ in sublinear time.

Note that when $k=2$, this is the classic Dirichlet's divisor problem which can be solved in $O(N^\frac{1}{3})$ using an algorithm described by the Polymath project [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.3956.pdf) or using the convex hull technique. But it seems hard to extend such method to higher dimensions keeping asymptotically the same complexity (or within logarithms); for example, for $k=3$ the naive extension yields $O(N^\frac{5}{9})$ complexity and as $k$ goes infinity, the time complexity approaches $O(N^{1-\epsilon})$.

Comment: What is "the convex hull technique"?